# Placing SCNNodes beside each other

Tags: ios, scenekit

Say I have three plane geometries, each showing a white plane (set via diffuse.contents). How can I get place the second and third SCNNodes beside each other?

My planes have the following dimensions:
(w, h)
(100, 100)
(200, 100)
(50, 100)

I've placed the first at (0, 0, -100). Now, I'd like the second to be placed to the right of the first, and the third to be placed to the right of the second.

Is the only option to track the X coordinate and keep incrementing it based on the previous SCNNode's width? Is it possible do to this in a better manner?

Answer (score 0):

This uses hard coded numbers you provided but you can always change it to be dynamic or fill in with functions to get the sizes runtime to have it be more friendly.  Depends on what you need.

```
nodeA.position = SCNVector3(0,0,-100)

// add half the width of nodeA to get the edge
let nodeAEdge : SCNVector3 = nodeA.position + SCNVector3(50,0,0)

// place center of nodeB half nodeB's width from the edge of nodeA
nodeB.position = nodeAEdge + SCNVector3(100,0,0)

// add half the width of nodeB to get the edge
let nodeBEdge : SCNVector3 = nodeB.position + SCNVector3(100,0,0)

// place center of nodeC half nodeC's width from the edge of nodeB
nodeC.position = nodeBEdge + SCNVector3(25,0,0)

// add all nodes to scene 

// Use this to overload the '+' to add two SCNVector3() (place outside the class)
func + (left: SCNVector3, right: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
    return SCNVector3Make(left.x + right.x, left.y + right.y, left.z + 
right.z)
}
```

Another way would be to get the boundingBox of each node.
Here's the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpath/1411165-boundingbox)

Comment: This leaves the positioning aspect of it to me, to track x, y and z for every single node :( I've solved it using this concept, but I'm looking to do this via some sort of a constraint. Since I'm used to auto layout, I'd love to see something that's really similar to that.